# PS3 Minecraft Main Account Exit Game

Tags: ps3, minecraft-legacy-console

I have Minecraft on my PS3. I play often with my family, with all four of us using the same PS3. When I have to leave, I would like to be able to exit the game, but I am the main account. If I exit the game, it shuts the game down and they cannot continue playing. The only thing I can do is leave my guy standing there waiting to be attacked. Is there any way to let those local players who are currently playing continue playing while the main account exits?

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can trap yourself in a hole and cover yourself up. Nothing will hurt you once you do this. I am a Xbox 360 player but I have seen the PS3 menu.

Comment: Well, there is still hunger :/

Comment: @ardaozkal hunger doesn't go down when standing still and not hurting.

Comment: @MrLemon oh, that is relieving.